# create column names by joining two labels of different levels with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

Is there a way to create column names directly by joining two labels from different levels of a table?
For example, let's say I have this data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n':[0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1],'l':[12 ,16 ,92, 77 ,32 ,47, 22, 14], 'cols':['col1','col1','col1','col1','col2','col2','col2','col2'], 'index':range(4)*2})
df_p = df.pivot(index='index', columns='cols')
```

and I'd like to add `l`/`n` to `col1`/`col2`. In the end I should have as many names as there are columns:

```
    col1_l   col2_l   col1_n   col2_n
    12       32       0        1
    16       47       1        1
    92       22       0        0
    77       14       0        1
```

I know I could do it this way:

```
names_l = df_p.l.columns + '_l'
names_n = df_p.n.columns + '_n' 
df_p.columns = names_l.append(names_n)
```

but perhaps there's a more direct way to do this that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *different* ways.  You want to combine the level names of the column multiindex, in reverse order, and join them with a `_`, so it feels like you're going to have to specify at least three things.  You could remove the dependence on the names, anyway, with something like

```
>>> df_p.columns = ['_'.join(c[::-1]) for c in df_p.columns]
>>> df_p
       col1_l  col2_l  col1_n  col2_n
index                                
0          12      32       0       1
1          16      47       1       1
2          92      22       0       0
3          77      14       0       1

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

which works because when you iterate over the original columns you get

```
>>> list(df_p.columns)
[('l', 'col1'), ('l', 'col2'), ('n', 'col1'), ('n', 'col2')]
```